# SAPUI5: How can I access ODataModel data programatically?

Tags: javascript, model, odata, sapui5, hana

When I create a model in code, I usually use:

```
var oData = {
  "name" : "",
  "description" : "",
  "phone" : ""
};
var oModel = new JSONModel(oData);
this.setModel(oModel, "data");
```

After that, I can access to the model and it's values using:

```
var oModel = this.getView().getModel("data");
var description = oModel.getProperty("/description");
```

But, that is using an internal json structure. How can I get the oModel structure when I use a oData destination from Hana Platform or when I use a mockup-server on my SAPUI5 project?

Comment: You can retrieve property data in the exact same way with ODataModel; what is your issue exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [getProperty](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#getProperty) method exists on an ODataModel (v2) as on any other model. Hence the usage differs a lot:

**How ODataModel stores data**

This is because the ODataModel stores data by it's keys, e.g.

```
{
  "EntitySet('Key-1')": {},
  "EntitySet('Key-2')": {},
  "EntitySet('Key-3')": {},
  "ExpandedEntitySet(EntityID='Key-3',ExpandedEntityIS='5')": {}
}
```

Check `oMyODataDataModel.oData` to see the actual stored data (but please do not use or manipulate it this way since this is internal API).

**ODataModels getProperty**

To retrieve a single entity you would have to say something like:

```
oDataModel.getProperty("/EntitySet('Key-1')");
```

Eventhough the binding path for the collection is `/EntitySet` requesting

```
oDataModel.getProperty("/EntitySet");
```

would return nothing. This happens because there is no entity in the internally stored data structure for oData["EntitySet"] and the `getProperty` method is still nothing else then a look-up in this internal structure.

**Include expanded entities**

One interesting thing with ODataModels `getProperty` method is the `bIncludeExpandEntries` parameter. If you set it to true the accessed entity will be returned including all potentially expanded NavigationProperties. In the above example

```
oDataModel.getProperty("/EntitySet('Key-3')");
```

will also return "ExpandedEntitySet(EntityID='Key-3',ExpandedEntityIS='5')" with it.

**ODataModels getObject**

ODataModels [`getObject`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.24/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#getObject) method has a lot more flexibility since it allows for the local use of the OData parameters `$select` and `$expand`. Getting an EntitySet is still not possible... NOTE: It will not load any missing data and the returned data may be incomplete!